# Wire tap as async channel?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

Is it right to use "wiretap" as a second line logic channel?

Or I should use another methods? I not found anything appropriate (pubSubChannel?)

For example:

```
    @Bean
HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway srvPutVers() {
    return Http.inboundGateway("/srvPutVers")
            .requestChannel("callLogicAndReply.input")
            .requestPayloadType(SomeRq.class)
            .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow callLogicAndReply() {
    return f -> f
            .wireTap("logicHard.input")
            .transform(p -> "{\"status\": \"Ok\"}");
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow logicHard() {
    return f -> f
            .log("hard logic");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that `wireTap("logicHard.input")` to be async, you need to start your `logicHard` flow from the `ExecutorChannel` with respective `Executor` injected. Or `QueueChannel`. See `IntegrationFlows` factory and its:

```
/**
 * Populate the {@link MessageChannel} object to the
 * {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder} chain using the fluent API from {@link MessageChannelSpec}.
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow} {@code inputChannel}.
 * @param messageChannelSpec the MessageChannelSpec to populate {@link MessageChannel} instance.
 * @return new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}.
 * @see org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels
 */
public static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(MessageChannelSpec<?, ?> messageChannelSpec) {
```

See that `MessageChannels` factory.

On the other hand if you talk about a parallel logic, then it is indeed better to take a look into the `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `Executor` option. Your `logicHard` flow logic might remain. Only what you need to have a global `PublishSubscribeChannel` bean and start that flow from this channel. In the main flow instead of `.wireTap("logicHard.input")` you need to use a plain `channel(myPublishSubscribeChannel())` to refer to the same bean.

Comment: say another way. 
What if I wand do some logic and continue old flow after channel wich I call by wireTap?

I thought Wiretap is like pubSucChannel, after reading https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/WireTap.html
because it's send same message in 2 channels

Comment: Your logic is OK and I still think my answer with an `ExecutorChannel` fits your expectations. Not sure what is your current struggle...